# Computer became really slow after Microsoft account sync

Tags: windows, windows-8, performance

My computer has always been very fast since I formatted and reinstalled Windows 8 x64.
Yesterday I did some things - the result is that my computer became VERY slow.

- Game performance is greatly decreased - even Doom 2 stutters.
- CPU and disk performance is greatly decreased - compiling my C++ projects takes 3x the time it took before
- Applications and explorer generally feel slower and sluggish

So, what did I do yesterday?

1. I bought a new microphone, and plugged it in
2. When I plugged the microphone in, I moved the case around (gently)
3. I installed Windows 8 x64 on my old laptop, logged in with my Microsoft account, and the setting synced between my desktop and my laptop. This is when I noticed the slowdown. I used system restore in order to go back to 28 February - this restored the original theme I had on my desktop. I disabled syncing on my desktop. Slowdown was still present. I cleaned the computer using CCleaner and Glary Utilities. Slowdown was still present. I booted in safe mode, cleaned Startup applications, Automatic services and unused drivers in the Device manager. I updated my video card drivers to the latest version. I ran Windows Update. Slowdown was still present.
4. Went to bed.

Today, I turned off the computer, unplugged all cables, opened the case, cleaned up the inside, checked if any cable was not connected properly. I plugged everything back in. Slowdown was still present.

I don't know what happened, and I don't want to format my computer again - there has to be a solution to the problem.

**Specs**

- OS: Windows 8 Enterprise x64
- CPU: i7 2700k @ 3.50GHz (Sandy Bridge 32nm)
- Ram: 8GB Corsair Vengeance DDR3
- Mobo: ASRock Z77 Extreme4-M
- GFX: GeForce GTX275
- SSD: OCZ-OCTANE 128GB

**Reports**

- DxDiag: http://pastebin.com/JYY5gJ5t
- CPU-Z: http://pastebin.com/bL81GSUd
- Speccy: http://pastebin.com/Mm7pXRg3

---

**Update**

I noticed RAM frequency (MHz) was way lower than expected. It should be 1600MHz, but it barely reaches 600MHz. I tried removing 1 stick of RAM, changing places, checking BIOS information. Still a lower frequency.

I tried a completely different stick of RAM (taken from another computer), that should be 1333MHz. It barely reached 500MHz.

Is it possible that an hypothetical electrical shock generated when I plugged in the microphone screwed up the motherboard? The microphone wasn't working right at first - I had to open it up and touch the cables to get it to work.

Comment: RAM frequency should be half of what is advertised. E.g. '1600' MHz RAM runs at 800MHz.    (DDR does twice the work per MHz so marketing doubled the numbers. But 667 real MHz for 1333 marketing MHz RAM is the same speed, so do not worry to much about that).

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone still have this problem, disconnecting your microsoft account from your pc fixed it for me.
In windows 10 you disconnect it in settings - account - and click log on with local account. Not sure if this will help anyone else than me, but I hope it does. I dont know how to keep the microsoft acccount and still not lag however.